# ASP.NET HttpHandler authentication problem in non-IE browser

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, swfupload

i have written a http handler for uploading multiple files from flex application.
In explorer it works properly, but in other browsers i have problem obiously with forms authentication..

this is log of the request from Firefox, Opera, etc..:

> /admin/UploadProductImage.axd?User=a6s55d4as6&Id=33
>   status: 302 (Found)
>   /admin/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2fUploadProductImage.axd%3fUser%3da6s55d4as6&Id=33
>   status: 200 (OK)

in Internet Explorer:

> /admin/UploadProductImage.axd?User=a6s55d4as6&Id=33
>   status: 200 (OK)

have anyone met with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is meant to happen? The first trace looks like what should happen if you are not logged in. It redirects to the login page. Isn't that what you want to have happen? Probably in the IE case, you had already logged in.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is meant to happen? Also, were you testing the case where the user is already logged in? Or where the user is not logged in?

Comment: I'm testing it when i'm logged in. I want to send a file from flash to HttpHandler, but when UploadProductImage.axd is called from flash in  Firefox then Request.IsAuthenticated is false and the request is redirected to login page.

Comment: You need to watch the network traffic with Fiddler or some other tool like it. In particular, you need to watch to see how cookies are passed between the client and server.